# Which is safer - using a self or this?

Tags: javascript, closures, this

Is it safe to use the keyword "this" to create new Locker? I am afraid that "this" may point to something else at the runtime. *I am new to JavaScript and closures.*

> ```
> var Employee = function() {
>     this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
> };
>
> _.extend(Employee.prototype, {
>     initialize : function(opts) {
>
>         this._locker = new Locker({
>             employee : this
>         });
>
>         // OR
>
>         var self = this;
>         this._locker = new Locker({
>             employee : self
>         });
>     }
> ```
>
> });

Comment: *this* has nothing to do with closures. Closures are formed by how code is written, *this* is set by how a function is called or set using *bind*.

Comment: I think you should read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to learn more about `this` first. Then you will hopefully see that the question whether to use `this` or not does not even apply in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this code in particular:

```
this._locker = new Locker({
    employee : this
});
```

Assuming that `this` already points to the right object, the above doesn't introduce a new scope; it would be the same as writing:

```
var options = {
    employee : this
};
this._locker = new Locker(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `self` in this case.

You will have seen `self` used when someone wishes to pass the value of `this` into a different scope as a closure.

```
var self = this;

var myFunc = function() {

    // do something with self (aka this)
};
```

In the example above `this` inside `myFunc` won't be known until the function is invoked - google 'dynamic vs static scoping' - and it won't be the '`this`' from outside of the function. That `this` is passed through as `self` in my example.

Note: that you don't have to use `self` any other variable name will do.

In your example you aren't attempting to pass `this` into a different scope so it should be fine.

Comment: Passing *this* is fine, it's referencing it that's the issue. *this* is always resolved in the current execution context, it never resolved on the scope chain, so it needs to be passed whenever its value is required in a different execution context.

Comment: ```this``` can't become a closure. You have to assign it to another var first. You can pass this as an argument to a function, but that's a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

Both snippets **act the same**.

The value of `this` is determined by *how* a function is called, so you are right in that `this` may point to something else at runtime.

However, once `initialize` has been called the value of `this` for that call has already been set. So:

```
    var self = this;
    this._locker = new Locker({
        employee : self
    });
```

Just adds an intermediate step, assigning `this` to a temporary variable (see [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21692428/3080396)'s) answer

Comment: For more information on how the value is determined, you should read [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (as Felix Kling pointed out in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

Your safer bet would be to use "this," since you are using apply and passing "this."  Apply will force "this" keyword to be the thisArg that you passed to the function.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

"self" is set to the Window object earlier in the initialization, but I don't think it changes after, unless you specifically change it.

Comment: Re `"self" is set to the Window object earlier in the initialization`. If you are referring to the OP, then no. *self* is set to the value of *this* when *initialize* is called, and since its *this* is set to the instance in the call, it will reference the instance, not *window* (or, more generally, the global object).

Comment: Thank you Rob for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to use the keyword "this" to create new Locker?

Yes.

```
> var Employee = function() {
>     this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
> };
```

Within a function called with *new* (i.e. called as a constructor), *this* will always point to the new instance. Using *apply* means that *arguments* is not passed as an Object, but as a sequence of values. So I think you should be doing:

```
function Employee () {
    this.initialize(arguments);
}
```

Note that function declarations are less code and more reliable than function expressions.

```
> _.extend(Employee.prototype, {
>     initialize : function(opts) {
```

Since you are calling this with *apply* and using *arguments* as the parameter object, the arguments are passed individually by value. So *opts* will be the first value of the arguments originally passed to the *Employee* constructor, the others will be available as members of this new function's *arguments* object.

```
> 
>         this._locker = new Locker({
>             employee : this
>         });
>     }
```

The value of *this* is set when a function is called (or by *bind*). In this case, *initialize* is intended to be called as a method of an instance so *this* will reference the instance. It could be called some other way so *this* references some other object (or any value if in strict mode), but the following has no effect on that.

This code doesn't make any difference to the value passed to *Locker*:

```
>     var self = this;
>     this._locker = new Locker({
>         employee : self
>     });
```

You seem to be trying to avoid a closure, but there is no closure here to avoid. Closures aren't caused by a function call, but by functions returning other functions that are created within them (through declarations or expressions). These functions continue to have access to the outer function's lexical environment after they have completed, e.g.

```
var foo = (function() {
  var bar = 'bar';
  return function(){ return bar;};
}());

foo(); // bar
```

The function *foo* has a closure to the variable *bar* declared in an outer function. No other function can access *bar* to read or set its value, it's only available to *foo* (this is how private members are emulated in javascript).

Where you run into trouble is where the value of the variable held in the closure is unexpectedly changed after the closure has been formed. That will not happen in the original code.